# Google free site search, post query

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, google-sites

I have a google site search

http://www.google.com/cse/manage/create

Which gives me the following working code:

```
<div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1', { language: 'en' });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('013080392637799242034:ichqh_hal4w');
        customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
        customSearchControl.draw('cse');
    }, true);
</script>
```

On some of my pages, I have a search box.  Can I make the text entered in that search box, post to this site search script and load?

For example:

- User is on Home.html
- They enter text in a search box
- Redirects them to Search.html
- Search.html takes the text they entered and does a search with it, without them needing to retype it in the empty box

At the moment I have:

```
// Temporary measure
SearchBox.click(function (event) {
    SearchBox.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    SearchBox.css("background", "#efefef");
    window.location.replace(Domainroot + "/search");
});
```

Which is less than ideal, but works OK.  When a user clicks the search box it redirects them to the search page to save them double entering the query.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/js/cselement-reference.html#_methods-el

It looks like the control you create comes with methods. It seems you are looking for the .execute(query) method.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have the iFrame code right on you homepage and you can customize it. You will find various ways to do it. But if you want to a more personalized thing like have a search box and then have results in your page then I would suggest you do a backend process to querying Google and then post back the results. Check Nokogiri example for what I mean.